# Significance of registration by Registrar General versus Assistant District Registrars in New South Wales

Tags: death-records, vital-records, australia, new-south-wales

I've just received a death certificate for someone I believe to be one of my ancestors from the NSW Registry of Births, Deaths and Marriages.

All the other NSW certificates that I have from around the time period are issued in the name of and signed by an Assistant District Registrar for the appropriate local office within the District of Sydney. The following certificates are from 1958 and 1966 respectively:

[image: 1958 NSW marriage certificate]

[image: 1966 NSW death certificate]

However, this 1957 death certificate is issued in the name of, and signed by, the state Registrar General:

[image: 1957 NSW death certificate]

I'm curious as to whether this is of any significance. One thing that stands out about this certificate is that a number of details are listed as unknown:

[image: unknown parental names and marriage date]

I'm wondering whether the lack of detail on the death registration statement might have caused it to be referred up the chain to head office in the city? Or are there other reasons why this particular death might not have been handled by the local district registrar?

Comment: What is the date of the registration compared to the date of death? In England there are all sorts of rules about when deaths should be registered and by who. If it was necessary to register a death outside those limits, I think that some sort of authority was needed. That might be the case here? What you need to find are the rules about registration in that state, at that time. A lot of our rules form part of government legislation.

Comment: @AdrianB38 date of registration is only 14 days after the death, so I don't think that has anything to do with it, but that definitely sounds like a similar situation which would raise flags and need special handling.

Comment: 14 doesn't sound excessive but I guess that the only way is to find the legislation and check through, particularly looking for reasons to require the RG to do the registration. The English and Welsh legislation is on a UK government site. I guess you need the equivalent for that state. Interesting.